# Setting the Sender/Recipient Fields of a new Phone Call Activity opened via openEntityForm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am working on a requirement to open a new Phone Call Activity Form with certain pre-filled details as below:
Sender (PartyList) should be set to a **CRM Contact** record 
Recipient (PartyList) should be set to a **CRM User** record
and some other basic details such as phone number and direction.

(**Note that the Sender is a Contact and Recipient is a User.This is different from CRM's by-default functionality which sets the Sender as current User**)

For this, I am using Xrm Utility's openEntityForm. However, I am not able to set the Sender and Recipient field as expected. Also, I found this official [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334375.aspx#BKMK_ExampleXrmUtilityOpentEntityForm) which says that we can not set PartyList and Regarding lookups like this.

I believe that there should be some way out to set these PartyList fields via openEntityForm since this seems to be a very basic CRM requirement. 
(Just while playing around this, I was able to set these fields via JScript)

Answer (score 0):

As you already found the MSDN article explained the limit:

> You can’t set the values for partylist or regarding lookups.

You can always add a custom lookup pointing to contact and set this lookup using parameters, after inside the OnLoad event (and check if FormType equals Create) you set the Sender by JavaScript copying the custom lookup value.

In the same way you can do the recipient.